# Showing attribute ( Manufacture, Size, Color ) on magento checkout success page

Tags: php, magento

actually i do this for retrieve my order details on magento checkout success page

```
<?php 
$order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id); 
$shipping_address_data = $order_details->getShippingAddress();
?>

             <tr> 
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Item Description') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Manufacture') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Color') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Size') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Unit Price') ?></th>
            </tr>      
        <?php foreach($order_details->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?> 
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $item->getName() ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->getManufacture() ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $item->getSize() ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $item->getColor() ?></td>
                <td><?php echo round($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo Mage::helper("core")->currency($item->getPrice()) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?> 

        <?php echo "<br>" . $shipping_address_data['country_name']; ?>
```

All is work fine except size, color, manufacture, and country name ( not showing )

Actually what's wrong with the code, anyone have a suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$item is not  `give whole product dat`a,it is give how may p`roduct item` was ordered and it product some product name ,qty etc.

If you want get product ,then you will need to load product by item product id.

```
     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$item->getSku());
       echo $_product->getManufacture() ;
        echo  $_product->getSize(); //size optionid
        echo  $_product->getColor(); //color otion id
echo $_product->getAttributeText('color');
echo $_product->getAttributeText('size'); // size optionlabel
```

Comment: what type of product used?? configurable

Answer (score 0):

use getAllItems instead of getAllVisibleItems

```
 <?php 
      foreach($order_details->getAllItems () as $item):
        echo "<pre>";print_r($item->getData());die;
      endforeach;
 ?>
```

print your result and check if you are getting the attributes value

Comment: just got it [product_options] => "attributes_info";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Color";s:5:"value";s:5:"Print";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Size";s:5:"value";s:2:"38" and then i am not sure to echo-ing it with this format @user3558854